# HTML Video tag is not working on safari and iphone device

Tags: iphone, safari, html5-video

I have spring MVC project where I have kept my video on resource folder (D:/folder/videos/) and same entry is made in my spring servlet xml  as like

In my jsp file I have below entry to show video

```
<div id="groupsign" class="tab-pane fade">

<video width="100%" height="400px" controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload" autoplay  loop  muted  playsinline >

<source src="<%=appUrl %>/videos/FirstVideo.mp4?preview=true" type="video/mp4">

<source src="<%=appUrl %>/videos/SecondVideo.mp4?preview=true" type="video/gg">

</video>

</div>
```

Still it not showing the video when run my application on server.  It showing blank and just searching symbol in video area.  This same code/video working on android device. If I replace video source by giving any public video link then its working. I am not getting what an issue and how to resolve the same.  Any guidance will help me more.

Safari

Used autoplay  loop  muted  playsinline  in video tag but not  luck

In Spring servlet configure resource folder like

```
<resources mapping="/videos/**" location="file:D:/folder/videos/"/ >
```

In JSP written video tag like

```
<video width="100%" height="400px" controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload" autoplay  loop  muted  playsinline >

<source src="<%=appUrl %>/videos/FirstVideo.mp4?preview=true" type="video/mp4">

<source src="<%=appUrl %>/videos/SecondVideo.mp4?preview=true" type="video/gg">

</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the ios mobile devices and solved it.

As mentioned here : Creating Video for Safari on iPhone: "HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback. (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support byte-range requests."

So you must check whether your server uses byte-range caching or else reconfigure it (I did it with nginx).

PS: Another secondary reason for ios video incompatibility could be the incompatible codecs of each video. The following compression standards are supported:

-H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. Note that B frames are not supported in the Baseline profile. -MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile) -AAC-LC audio, up to 48 kHz